# Trying to containerize my ASP.NET application with Kubernetes(K8s)

Tags: asp.net, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to containerize, my database deployment is set up correctly because it's running with no problems.
Here is my sql deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: sql-server-dentist
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: "sql-server"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sql-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sql-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sql-server-dentist-container
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
          env:
            - name: ACCEPT_EULA
              value: "Y"
            - name: SA_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: sql-server-secret
                  key: SA_PASSWORD
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1433
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        storageClassName: "standard"
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sql-server
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 1433
  selector:
    app: sql-server
```

Here is my secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: sql-server-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  SA_PASSWORD: <hashed-password-changed-to-ask>
```

My application deployment with two replicas and a service that is a load balancer

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dentist-web-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dentist-web-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dentist-web-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: dentist-web-app-container
          image: guimarkes457/odonto-control:latest
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: ConnectionStrings_DefaultConnection
              value: "Server=sql-server-dentist;Database=OdontoControlDb;User Id=sa;Password=<my-password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dentist-service-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: dentist-web-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I think the cause is that my deployment environment variables is not overriding my connection string that is presented in the appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=sqlserver;Database=OdontoControlDb;User Id=SA;Password=<my-password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;Encrypt=false"
  },
```

Here is my services and deployments running, sql is running correctly but every 25s my pod try to restart the pods.

```
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
pod/dentist-web-app-7b79bf8664-crvp8   1/1     Running   5 (3h41m ago)   3h44m
pod/dentist-web-app-7b79bf8664-lsj8l   1/1     Running   5 (3h41m ago)   3h44m
pod/sql-server-dentist-0               1/1     Running   3 (3h40m ago)   2d3h

NAME                          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/dentist-service-app   LoadBalancer   10.100.200.193   <pending>     80:31858/TCP   2d3h
service/kubernetes            ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        27d
service/sql-server            ClusterIP      10.106.76.73     <none>        1433/TCP       2d3h

NAME                              READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/dentist-web-app   2/2     2            2           3h44m

NAME                                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/dentist-web-app-7b79bf8664   2         2         2       3h44m

NAME                                  READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/sql-server-dentist   1/1     2d3h
```

Can anyone help me?

My app pod be connected to the sql service

Comment: Please don't post images of text. They're hard to search and hard to copy/paste from. Edit your post and place the text in it. Then use the formatting tools to make it look nice.

Comment: Ok I'll do it, thanks

Comment: You've named your Service `sql-server` (with a hyphen, without "dentist") and that's the name that should be in your connection string.

Comment: Even though I changed my connection string in the appsettings.json "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=sql-server-dentist;Database=OdontoControlDb;User Id=SA;Password=<my-passoword>;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;Encrypt=false"
  }, it did not fix the bug, and my point here is that my deployment change my connection string overriding it, so in my app I still got my connection string and when I deploy in k8s I get my overrided acessing the sql service

Comment: And I updated my image in the Docker hub but still getting same error